# Compare an int with double array

Tags: c, compare, double

I'm trying to learn C and I want to make a program that compares the number I type with the numbers in my array. The only problem is that It doesn't actually do that. Even if I type a number that is from that array it shows that the number is not from that array.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void getMark(int findMark, double crswk1[]);
    void changePartMark(double crswk1[], int findMark);

    int main()
    {
    int findMark;
    double crswk1[10]={67, 77, 80, 40};

    getMark(findMark, crswk1);
    changePartMark(crswk1, findMark);
}

void getMark(int findMark, double crswk1[])
{
    printf("Enter the mark you want to change: ");
    scanf("%d", &findMark);

}

void changePartMark(double crswk1[], int findMark)
{
    int i;
        if(findMark == crswk1[i])
            {
            printf("It is equal");
            }
        else
            {
            printf("It is not equal");
            }
}
```

Comment: Be warned of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you're reading in is never getting back to `findMark` in your `main` function.

```
void getMark(int findMark, double crswk1[])
{
    printf("Enter the mark you want to change: ");
    scanf("%d", &findMark);

}
```

This function is saving a value in the local parameter `findMark`.  Because all parameters in C are passed by value, changes to this local variable are not reflected in the caller, so `findMark` in `main` never changes.

You need to change this function to take the *address* of an `int

```
void getMark(int *findMark, double crswk1[])
{
    printf("Enter the mark you want to change: ");
    scanf("%d", findMark);
}
```

Then you call this function from `main` like this:

```
getMark(&findMark, crswk1);
```

By passing in the address of `findMark`, the function can write to that address.

Also, your `changePartMark` function doesn't search through the entire array.  It only looks at index `i`.  But even that is a problem because you never set `i`.

You need to loop through the array to check your value against each element in the array.

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<4 i++) {
    if(findMark == crswk1[i])
        {
        printf("It is equal");
        }
    else
        {
        printf("It is not equal");
        }
}
```

Comment: And what if I just want it to show It is equal, without showing It is not equal for every number that is not the number I want

Comment: @nikunikuD Have another variable that flags whether or not you found a match, initializing it to false.  If you find a match, set the flag to true, otherwise do nothing.  When the loop is done, check the value of the flag.

Answer (score 1):

Two main issues:

First, the number you enter is never passed back. When you write

```
void getMark(int findMark, double crswk1[]) {
    printf("Enter the mark you want to change: ");
    scanf("%d", &findMark);
}
```

then you read in the value in a local copy `findMark`, not in the one used by the caller. BTW: `crswk1` is not used; So I'd suggest to write

```
int getMark() {
    int findMark = 0;
    printf("Enter the mark you want to change: ");
    scanf("%d", &findMark);
    return findMark;
}
```

Second, your `void changePartMark(double crswk1[], int findMark)` lacks a loop, and `i` is not initialized. Code could look like the following:

```
void changePartMark(double crswk1[], int findMark)
{
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if(findMark == crswk1[i])
            {
            printf("It is equal");
            }
        else
            {
            printf("It is not equal");
            }
    }
}
```